# How to exchange data from android to a (html + php) server?

Tags: php, android, network-protocols

I have in a server web page in html + php and I need that information is exchanged in both directions with Andorid application.

For example if the server had some language like python or java (It is not the case), normally I would use a socket server that is running continuously. But using php, I think it's not a good way because it has a maximum time limit of run script and the socket server would be run indefinitely waiting for clients.

The idea is to have a html form, where data of Android phone in real time can be seen, and also can send commands to andorid from html interface.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: AJAX polling, Comet, etc.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology has a few possibilities.

Comment: for sending data (using GET or POST) to android use NanoHTTPd (https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)

Comment: It is very unclear what you want. Normally you have a webserver who can execute php scripts. There are hundreds of examples on this forum how to post or get data to a url and retrieve the response. I do not understand what `a html form where data from android phone can be seen`. Wich data from that phone? `can send commands from html interface` ????

Comment: For example, I need to see the battery level of Andorid phone in a html page or activate a sound alarm in Android phone from html page.